# How to show microphone level in a ProgressBar using Naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to capture the microphone/input levels in a ProgressBar using Naudio. I'm able to get a list of devices in my combobox, but the sound meter level isn't showing in the ProgressBar (sort of like a VU/Peak meter.) Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;


namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = deviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
            if (devices != null)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
            }
        }
        void Mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device = (MMDevice)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
               progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you started recording? You generally only see meter levels when you are capturing audio.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added `MyTimer.Start();` function in `Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)` Event.